# How to fill the missing date values in data frame by generating the range of dates between two time periods

Tags: python, data-science

I have a dataframe in which few date values for date column are missing and all other data values are present. I have to fill the date values. The date values must be in between the two values. For e.g fill the missing dates between the 13/12/1988 to 20/01/2012.

Please help me.

Many Thanks,
Aniket Patel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime.timedelta function to get a time offset. This can be used to generate every date from time `a` to time `b`.

```
a = datetime.datetime(1988, 12, 13)
b = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 20)

# get all date between a and b
date_list = [a + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((b - a).days)]

# format dates for pretty printing
date_str_list = ['{}/{}/{}'.format(d.year, d.month, d.day) for d in date_list]

# print first five dates
print(date_str_list[:5])
```

Comment: Hi There, Thanks for quick reply.  There are 37 date values missing in my dataframe. I have generated the dates using the function.....                                                            
 def random_dates(start, end, n=37):

    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9

    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')              .. I have to fill these values in the missing values in the dataframe. Kiundly help.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date to timedeltas since epoche in seconds. Call pandas `interpolate` function for this series. Convert back if you want to have the date-representation

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10)))
df.iloc[5]['date'] = ''

        date
0 2013-01-01
1 2013-01-02
2 2013-01-03
3 2013-01-04
4 2013-01-05
5        NaT
6 2013-01-07
7 2013-01-08
8 2013-01-09
9 2013-01-10

in_sec = pd.to_timedelta(df['date'], unit='second') / np.timedelta64(1, 's')

result = in_sec.interpolate()

result = pd.to_datetime(result ,unit='s')

0   2013-01-01
1   2013-01-02
2   2013-01-03
3   2013-01-04
4   2013-01-05
5   2013-01-06
6   2013-01-07
7   2013-01-08
8   2013-01-09
9   2013-01-10
```

Comment: Hi Raja, Thanks for quick reply.  There are 37 date values missing in my dataframe. I have generated the dates using the function.....                                                            
 def random_dates(start, end, n=37):

    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9

    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')              .. I have to fill these values in the missing values in the dataframe. Kiundly help.

Comment: These values are not missing. They are just wrong. Right? So you have to find them first, delete them and afterwards interpolate. Finding them depends on how wrong they are. But you should clarify that in your question. Because now it is a different questions. Finding wrong values in datetimes or so...